# How to push array inside a object with arrays in React js?

Tags: reactjs

I have an issue,

I have a select control component, which has options, inside options I'm adding array of options by mapping array `staticPosts`.

**My code:**

```
<SelectControl
    label={__("Choose Static Block Page to show above header", "pirezmeta")}
    onChange={ (value) => props.onChangeStaticContent(value) }
    options={props.staticPosts && props.staticPosts.map(post => 
        ({value: post.id, label: post.title}))}
    value={props.staticContent}
/>
```

Everything is fine, except I want to add empty option first, something like: `{value: 0, label: "No value"}`
How can I do it, can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot is going on in that prop. I'd declare the array above, separately - include the first `{value: 0, label: "No value"}` item, then add in the other mapped items:

```
const options = [
  {value: 0, label: "No value"},
  ...props.staticPosts?.map(
    post => ({value: post.id, label: post.title})
  )
];
// ...
<SelectControl
    label={__("Choose Static Block Page to show above header", "pirezmeta")}
    onChange={ (value) => props.onChangeStaticContent(value) }
    options={props.staticPosts && options}
    value={props.staticContent}
/>
```

You could also put the combined array into state on mount or when the props change.